# filter 2 data in 1 cell with Ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filtering, ag-grid

I'm displaying 2 data in 1 cell with Ag-Grid and i want to create a filter for every data. The filtering used to work with one data but now i doesn't anymore. here is a screenshot of my Grid:
[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAzfL.png)

I want to display the 2 headers below each other and add filter to each header. Here is my code how i used the simple filtering in `app-component.ts` :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Grid, GridApi } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { DealsService } from './services/deals.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import {DateCellRendererComponent} from 'src/app/date-cell-renderer/date-cell-renderer.component'
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'app';
gridOptions = {
rowHeight :90,
headerHeight:60
}
columnDefs = [
{headerName: "Block \n Deal", cellRenderer: function(params){ return params.data.BLOCKID + '<br/>' + params.data.DEALID },width:150, resizable:true, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'} ,
{headerName: 'Class \n Type', cellRenderer: function(params){ return params.data.DEALCLASS + '<br/>' + params.data.DEALTYPE },width:150, resizable:true, filter: true} ,
{headerName: 'Trade \n Start',cellRendererFramework: DateCellRendererComponent ,width:150, resizable:true, filter: 'agDateColumnFilter' } ,
{headerName: 'Folder \n Cpty', cellRenderer: function(params){ return params.data.FOLDERSHORTNAME + '<br/>' + params.data.CPTYSHORTNAME },width:150, resizable:true, filter: true} ,
{headerName: 'ShortName \n Name', cellRenderer: function(params){ return params.data.INSTRSHORTNAME + '<br/>' + params.data.INSTRNAME },width:150, resizable:true, filter: true, } ,

{headerName: 'Quantity \n Settl.Amt',cellRenderer: function(params){ return params.data.QUANTITY + '<br/>' + params.data.SETTLEAMT },width:150, resizable:true, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'} ,
{headerName: 'Rate \n Fees', cellRenderer: function(params){ return params.data.FLOATINGRATESSHORTNAME + '<br/>' + params.data.RENTSPREADFIXEDRATE },width:150, resizable:true, filter: true} ,
{headerName: 'Category \n Status',cellRenderer: function(params){ return params.data.DEALCAT + '<br/>' + params.data.WORKFLOWSTATE },width:150, resizable:true, filter: true} ,
{headerName: 'End', field : 'ENDDATE',valueFormatter : this.dateFormatter,width:140, resizable:true, filter : 'agDateColumnFilter'}




];

rowData : any;

constructor(private service:DealsService) {



}
dateFormatter(params){
return moment(params.value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}


ngOnInit() {
this.service.getDealsList().subscribe(data => {
this.rowData = data;
}); }

}
```

and here is my `app-component.html` :

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-balham" ng-grid="gridOptions"
style="width: 1350px; height: 630px;"
class="ag-theme-alpine"
[rowData]="rowData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
[animateRows]="true"
[paginationPageSize]="10"
[pagination]="true"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

I'm really thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm that's not possible with the ag-grid filters I guess (I'm not 100% sure).
I think that it only might be possible using the `custom filter component`

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/